# fetching the bool value of one class from another class in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a class(PowerUp) in which i have a bool Mag which is publicly declared

when i try to access that bool from another class(Result)

```
                     // class Result

      if(PowerUP.Mag)// need to return the bool value from class PowerUp
  {
              // code to run if powerup.mag is true

        CoinCollectedCounter ++;
        CoinCounterText.text = ""+CoinCollectedCounter;
        col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
  }
```

am not getting the bool value..actually it returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your script is attached to a game object on the scene:

`GameObject.Find("MyGameObject").GetComponent<PowerUp>().Mag;`

When your script is not attached:

```
PowerUp powerUp; // creating object
powerUp.Mag; // getting variable
```

Answer (score -2):

to access the bool of an another class it should be declared static

in class powerup the bool Mag should be declared as

```
public static bool Mag;
```

so after this declaration the code works

```
      // class Result

  if(PowerUP.Mag)// need to return the bool value from class PowerUp
  {
          // code to run if powerup.mag is true

    CoinCollectedCounter ++;
    CoinCounterText.text = ""+CoinCollectedCounter;
    col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
  }
```

Comment: Static variables retain one value throughout the execution of the game. Rather get the script instance through `GetComponent<PowerUp>()` and just use this instance to access the value.